# Каким образом реализовать выборку из базы?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. На сайте реализовал добавление товара. И для товара реализована создание полей характеристик.
Вопрос: Каким образом сделать выборку из базы, если я не могу построить запрос заранее, так как не знаю по каким полям будет идти выборка, так как поля создаются динамически?

Comment: это называется EAV - Entity–attribute–value (сущность-атрибут-значение). Как по мне - тема слишком широкая и проще очень много статей на эту тему почитать в инете

Comment: А вы искать не пробовали, говорят помогает. Особенно для таких вопросов, которые с периодичностью раз в неделю задают. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выборка по точным вхождениям](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664287/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc)

Answer (score 0):

Что-то такое сделайте - в переменных имена нужных полей:

```
$result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT ".$col1.",".$col2." FROM Products")
```

Answer (score -2):

Динамически формировать запрос, ведь все равно есть доступ к динамическим полям, вот по ним и формировать динамикой запрос в бд, можно сначала сформировать некий WHERE в переменую, и только в конце уже делать запрос в БД приклеив переменую