# Как проще реализовать фильтр товаров?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Здравствуйте. Задача следующая: Реализовать создание **Групп**, в каждой Группе реализовать возможность создания полей(характеристик). 
После реализовать добавление товара, при добавлении товара выбираем ему ранее созданные характеристики из Групп, и задаем им значения.

Вопрос: Каким образом реализовать это, если учесть что для всего этого нужен будет фильтр, который должен будет отбирать товары по заданным параметрам, по созданным характеристикам.

Пример фильтра:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На мой взгляд вся сложность в том что заранее не определено сколько будет полей характеристик, так как они создаются через админку, поэтому не могу заранее построить запрос к базе.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [EAV модели данных](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Каким образом реализовать выборку из базы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663698/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b)

Comment: @vikolyada самое смешное, что я уже это рекомендовал человеку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/663698/191482  ....но кажется он слишком не хочет слышать и видеть ничего, что ему пишут

Answer (score 3):

[image: Модель данных]

Можно начать примерно с такой модели. В админке при добавлении новой группы товаров задаем им требуемые виды характеристик. Поле "тип" может принимать значения, например, "строка", "число","перечислимый". Его можно сделать например типа ENUM или числом и добавить еще таблицу с названиями этих типов. Или использовать некие кодовые обозначения, удобные программе. Для перечислимых типов в одноименной таблице заводим возможные значения параметра, на основе них будут формироваться выпадающие списки вроде "тип двигателя".

При добавлении товара выбираем и предлагаем задать все виды характеристик, определенные для данной группы товаров. С тем как хранить возможные значения есть варианты: можно в виде строки в единственное поле "Значение" (таблицы "Значения характеристик"), можно завести несколько колонок в зависимости от типа: строка, число или ссылка на ID перечислимого типа. Смотрите как вам удобнее.

Ссылочную целостность правда поддерживать на уровне БД можно только триггерами, могут потребоваться проверки, что бы к товару было невозможно добавить характеристики не его группы. И в случае единственного поля под значение контролировать для перечислимых типов, что в поле id существующей записи из таблицы перечислимых типов. А так же обеспечить невозможность удаления записи перечислимого типа, если она используется в каких то товарах.

Модель может дополнительно усложняться, появляться связующие таблицы, если например вы захотите возможность относить товар сразу к нескольким группам или, например, есть некие общие характеристики для нескольких групп и их хотелось бы оставить именно общими, что бы например была возможность выбрать все товары весом более тонны из всех групп.