# Выборка по точным вхождениям

Tags: php, mysql

Реализована возможность динамического создания полей характеристик для товара.
Задача: Сделать фильтр по характеристикам. Почти все сделал. Но есть одна проблемка. Выводит товары в характеристиках которых, есть хотя бы одно совпадение.
То есть, если я выбираю АВТО - выводит все товары которые являются АВТО, потом я выбираю КРАСНЫЕ - выводит опять же все товары АВТО + КРАСНЫЕ. А, например, АВТО СИНИЕ выводятся тоже.

Запрос:

```
$item = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `id_item` FROM `x-ka` WHERE (id_pole, value) in ($in)");
```

Где `in` - значения, которые создаются при запросе, так как заранее нельзя определить все возможные поля характеристик.

Буду благодарен за любую полезную информацию.

Comment: Мне интересно, вы комментарии к своим вопросам читаете ? я вам к почти такому же вопросу рекомендовал посмотреть вот это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506498/  отличия от вашего запроса, т.к. слева два поля, то и в IN не просто значения, а заключенные в скобки пары, а во вторых там явно был указан having, который как раз решает то что вы спрашиваете - обеспечивает поиск по точному совпадению всех фильтров

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `id_item` 
FROM `x-ka` 
WHERE (id_pole, value) in ($in)
GROUP BY `id_item` 
HAVING COUNT(`id_item`) = $pairs_count_in_$in
```

Answer (score 0):

судя по описанию, у вас все характеристики — в одной таблице. и в ней явно присутствует ещё и идентификатор товара.

значит, для выборки идентификаторов товаров, у которых совпадают характеристики, надо использовать объединения (`join`).

вот ориентировочные примеры для двух и трёх совпадающих характеристик:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7397eb/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table x (id int, tovar int, name text);

insert into x (id, tovar, name) values
  (0, 1, 'авто')
 ,(1, 1, 'красные')
 ,(2, 1, 'длинные')
 ,(3, 2, 'авто')
 ,(4, 2, 'синие')
 ,(5, 2, 'длинные')
 ,(6, 3, 'авто')
 ,(7, 3, 'красные')
 ,(8, 3, 'короткие')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
/* для двух характеристик */
select x1.tovar from x x1
left join x x2 on
 x2.tovar = x1.tovar and x2.id <> x1.id
where
 x1.name = 'авто' and x2.name = 'красные'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7397eb/2/0)**:

```
| tovar |
|-------|
|     1 |
|     3 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
/* для трёх характеристик */
select x1.tovar from x x1
left join x x2 on
 x2.tovar = x1.tovar and x2.id <> x1.id
left join x x3 on
 x3.tovar = x1.tovar and x3.id <> x1.id
where
 x1.name = 'авто' and x2.name = 'красные' and x3.name = 'длинные'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7397eb/2/1)**:

```
| tovar |
|-------|
|     1 |
```